# What is the best way to integrate Pycharm Python into a MySQL CE Database?

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm, mysql-python

I have set up a database using MySQL Community Edition to log serial numbers of HDD's and file names. I am instructed to find a way to integrate Python scripting into the database so that the logs can be entered through python programming instead of manually (as manually would take a ridiculous amount of time.) Pycharm was specified as the programming tool that will be used, I have done research for the past few days and haven't found any solid way that this should be done, the python connector doesn't appear to be able to work with Pycharm. Any suggestions?

Comment: PyCharm is a development environment, no way MySQL will have a way to make it work. You would be good getting a way in which mysql can execute a specific program file (eg. a .py, .exe or .bat file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading between the lines here. I believe what you are being asked to do is called ETL. If somebody were to ask me to do the above my approach would be

1. Force an agreed upon format for the incoming data (probably a .csv)
2. Write a python application to; a. Read the data from the csv, b. Condition the data if necessary, c. Write the results to the database

Pycharm would be the tool that I would use to write my Python code. It would have nothing to do with MySql. The ETL process should be initiated from the command line so you can automate it. So you need to research the following for python.

- Reading files from a csv
- Parsing command line arguments
- Connecting and writing to a MySql database

Again, I'm doing some guessing here as your question is vague.

SteveJ